# Magic Mouse not working in macOS Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, mojave

I update my Macbook Pro* today to macOS Mojave 10.14 (18A391).

I have a Magic Mouse that I've been using for years and that has so far always worked.

However, now the right click with that Magic Mouse does no longer work. I can do a right click with two fingers on my Trackpad but not using the mouse.

I checked the settings and **Secondary click** is enabled.

[image: secondary click ![secondary]

Double-tap to zoom does work fine.

[image: right-click-not-working]

<sub>* MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)</sub>

Comment: sound like MM problem. Do they offer updates ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: The right click worked just a day ago when I still had High Sierra. So I don't think it's the MM problem. Unfortunately I can't test it right now with another mac.

Comment: sounds like the communication protocol between MM and mac Bluetooth is broken

Comment: I have been having this problem too, and I've been doing the command-alt-p-r thing and that works for a few days too. Also only since 14.1.1, on 2012 Retina MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved it by deleting:

- `com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist`, and
- `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist`

files from user `~/Library/Preferences/` directory.

Comment: This worked for me, too. However, I needed to enable the secondary click in System Preferences after removing both files and restarting my Mac.

Comment: This worked. First delete the .plist, then connect the mouse with a cable so it create a new profile. Also I turned off then on the bluethooth

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and deleting the above files and rebooting didn't change anything.  Also tried resetting the Bluetooth module and factory resetting all connected Bluetooth devices.  Interestingly, I only noticed the issue after updating to Mojave 10.14.1.  When I was on 10.14 the magic mouse was working fine.

Comment: Very useful - thank you! This fixed my magic mouse that had been working happily until I installed Mojave. The upgrade to 10.14.1 didn't make a difference.

Comment: Tried everything without success, seems i need to reinstall macOS (press Option+Command+R while restarting).

Answer (score 4):

Lets try to fix the BT

Hold Shift + Option and click on BT in the menu bar.

Then select Debug.

[image: does anyone reads this]

Then do the obvious.

Comment: I did not know the Shift + Option trick. Good to know. I did reset the device and had to re-pair the device but the right click still does not work as you may see in my updated question.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't leave the last step up to the imagination. I selected the "factory reset..." option, then re-paired the devices in the Bluetooth interface. That solved the scrolling issue. If that is your suggested approach, please include it. If not, please provide your explicit alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I did this too.  Still doesn't work.  What is weird is that I connected the magic mouse to my old iMac running Lion and the right click works just fine.  I did all the troubleshooting steps but to no avail.  I went and bought a new Magic Mouse 2, and the right click works just fine.  Kinda sucks that I had to buy a new mouse, but now I have a nice mouse for the old iMac!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess there has to be some other way. I could imagine that this will be fixed in a Mojave update at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to repeatedly remove the mouse from the Bluetooth connections list and repair, which works a while (day or so) before it goes 'missing' again. Haven't found a solution yet that fixes the issue!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your inputs. Since you haven't discovered a specific solution to this problem I would suggest adding your inputs as a comment rather than an answer.